# sudo and su do not work in a newly installed fedora 30

Tags: fedora, sudo, su

I just installed Fedora 30 and I am trying to get my head around it. I need to install lots of stuff from the command line but when I run `sudo` the system tells me that the command does not exist. (if I try to install it the installation fails because it already exists (?))

I try running `su -` and it asks for a password, which I have no idea what it is. I wasn't prompted for a root password during installation (from a live USB).

Any idea how to get around this?

**EDIT 1:**
As per roaima's request, this is the output of my `echo "$PATH"`:

```
/home/yazan/.local/bin:/home/yazan/bin:/usr/share/Modules/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
```

**EDIT 2:**
this is the result of running `rpm --verify sudo` (in case it helps)

```
..?......  c /etc/sudoers

missing     /usr/bin/sudo

..?......    /usr/bin/sudoreplay

missing     /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/sudo.conf

missing     /usr/libexec/sudo/group_file.so

missing     /usr/libexec/sudo/libsudo_util.so.0.0.0

missing     /usr/libexec/sudo/sesh

missing     /usr/libexec/sudo/sudo_noexec.so

missing     /usr/libexec/sudo/sudoers.so

missing   d /usr/share/doc/sudo/HISTORY

missing     /var/db/sudo/lectured (Permission denied)

**and the sudoers:**

ls -l /etc/sudoers

-r--r-----. 1 root root 3276 Mar 11 05:09 /etc/sudoers
```

**EDIT 3:**
Okay, I think a got a but further but going into the GRUB menu, editing the "linux" line, appending init="/bin/sh", loading the policy, mounting the root partition, and resetting the root password.

The root password was only accepting one capital letter character. Anything other than that would return a palindrome password error as you type past the first character.

anyway, I can run su - and login as root now (not the best practice I know), but my other account - although it exists in the "wheel" group, is not able to use sudo. Installing and resintalling sudo does not fix the problem.

Why do I need to hack into my own system to fix it? and how do I get to use sudo for heaven's sake?

Comment: Please add result of `echo "$PATH"` to your question

Comment: /home/yazan/.local/bin:/home/yazan/bin:/usr/share/Modules/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin

Comment: does it work if you use `pkcon` to remove and re-install `sudo`? You could also try `pkexec dnf ...` or `systemd-run dnf ...`

Comment: if the `sudo` package was so broken, it is probably worth looking at `sudo rpm --verify --all` as well.

Comment: @sourcejedi I reinstalled fedora again today, same thing. I don't think that the package is broken on a fresh install. I reinstalled it several times and got the same thing.